# Solving double integral by changing to polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I have this question in my review problems for multivariable calculus. The hint is to change the coordinates to polar coordinates, however, I am not sure how to change the limits of the integrals. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated!

$$\int_{0}^{2a} \int_{-\sqrt{2ay-y^2}}^{0} \sqrt{x^2+y^2} dxdy$$

In this problem, a is a positive number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work out exactly what the region is, then describe that region in terms of polar instead of rectangular coordinates. The first task is to figure out what the graph of $x=-\sqrt{2ay-y^2}$ look like.

HINT: If $x=-\sqrt{2ay-y^2}$, then $x^2=2ay-y^2$, and $x^2+(y-a)^2=a^2$.